# Creating an IList<T> of Item<U>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-3.0

So I have an object, lets say `Item<U>`.  I want to create a(n) `(I)List<T>` containing a collection of these items.  The problem that I am running into is that the collection of `Item<U>` can have any number of different types for U in them.

What I can not figure out is the signature to use for the `IList`.  I tryed `IList<Item<T>>`, but because I do not (in the class where the `IList` is to be used) have a defination of `T` (which as I said varys anyhow) I can not use this signature.  What is the best way to approach this requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a non-generic interface to your `Item<U>` and make the collection out of those interfaces.

There is no way you can create a collection of `IList<Item<T>>` where T is some base type for a lot of different object types you want to place into the same list. This is co(ntra)-variance in place which specifically prohibits this.

So you need to instead add something common, that isn't generic, and make the list out of that. For instance, you might make `Item<T>` implement `IItem`, and create `IList<IItem>` instead.

That's the best you can do.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanist way to accomplish what I need.  For some reason, it just did not come to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An IList is meant to hold a single type. To decide if something is a "single type" or not, you have to expand all the type parameters. Taking your example of an `IList<Item<T>>`, the `T` would have to be one and only one thing for a particular instance.

For example, you can pick `Animal` for `T` and then proceed to put `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Bear` instances in the `IList`. But you can't put arbitrary types there; they have to be able to be converted to the type you specify for `T`. And if your types *are* and not related in this way, you don't have any choice except to have a non-generic interface for your list. You could also consider defining an interface type for T that all your eligible items can conform to.

Once you've decided what `T` will be, you can then make your method generic:

```
public void PrintItems<T>(IList<Item<T>> list)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your method generic, like:

```
public void DoSomethingWithTheList<T>(IList<Item<T>> theList)
{
    //Do that something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a pain in .Net 3, because all the Item for different U are treated as independent types. To make it work you have to manually introduce an interface for this type:

```
interface IItem{}

class Item<U>:IItem {...}
```

and now you can:

```
IList<IItem> list = new IList<IItem>();
list.Add(new Item<string>());
list.Add(new Item<int>());
```

Alternatively you could stick to the non-generic list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
class Item<U>
{
   ...
}


class Item : Item<object> {
   ...
}

....
IList<Item> itemList;
```

Comment: You still can't put an Item<int> and and Item<string> into itemList. Normally you'd do class Item {} class Item<T> : Item { } to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you just want an `IList<Item<U>>`. The key is that the `T` in the name of the generic type `IList<T>` is just a placeholder - it doesn't have any special meaning. You want a list of `Item<U>`s, so just make one.

Now, this will of course mean that the method / class that contains this `IList` will itself be generic in `U`, but that seems to be dictated by the terms of your question.